# Cannot install PyQt6 tools in Python 3.11 on Windows

Tags: python, pip, pyqt6

I installed the `Python 3.11` pre-release on my Windows 11 computer:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110a7/

I installed it in the folder `C:\Python311\`

Then I launched a command prompt and installed `wheel`, `pyqt6` and `pyqt6-tools`. As you can see, something goes wrong when installing `pyqt6-tools`:

```sh
>pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.37.1
```

```sh
>pip install pyqt6
Collecting pyqt6
  Downloading PyQt6-6.3.0-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 6.2/6.2 MB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting PyQt6-sip<14,>=13.2
  Downloading PyQt6_sip-13.3.1.tar.gz (108 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 108.3/108.3 KB 6.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting PyQt6-Qt6>=6.3.0
  Downloading PyQt6_Qt6-6.3.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (45.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 45.8/45.8 MB 11.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: PyQt6-sip
  Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for PyQt6-sip: filename=PyQt6_sip-13.3.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl size=71550 sha256=4bc5340bdce65cccb581389f646d712aa78abbdae84d461120e9565426dc93c8
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-jmbk1_kb\wheels\c3\af\39\f00fa6b0b54378c6b571e7d38750537a92e95390d4247d3b9e
Successfully built PyQt6-sip
Installing collected packages: PyQt6-Qt6, PyQt6-sip, pyqt6
Successfully installed PyQt6-Qt6-6.3.0 PyQt6-sip-13.3.1 pyqt6-6.3.0
```

```sh
>pip install pyqt6-tools
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Downloading pyqt6_tools-6.1.0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Downloading pyqt6_tools-6.0.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting click
  Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 96.6/96.6 KB 5.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Downloading pyqt6_tools-6.0.2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.0.2
  Downloading PyQt6-6.0.2.tar.gz (940 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 940.8/940.8 KB 6.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
          ^^^^^^
        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1ejos5sl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1ejos5sl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1ejos5sl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tat_ias8\pyqt6_920842ce0fe64e4a89597e45e5a8549f\project.py", line 60, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1ejos5sl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1ejos5sl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\krist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1ejos5sl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I thought the reason could be related to access rights. So I launched a cmd prompt in admin mode. Unfortunately, the problem remains.

Comment: As far as I know, PyQt* tools are not yet supported even on Python 3.10.

Answer (score 6):

Here a complete guide to install pyqt6 on Python 3.11

1. Download the file from pypi. This is the link: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6/#files. Download the version for windows with the name "PyQt6-6.4.1-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl"
2. Rename the file to "PyQt6-6.4.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl"
3. Download now the file of plugins, also from pypi. This is the link: https://pypi.org/project/pyqt6-plugins/#files. Download the file named "pyqt6_plugins-6.1.0.2.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"
4. Rename this last file to "pyqt6_plugins-6.1.0.2.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl"
5. Now, with WinRar (or similar) open this last file, that now is renamed as "pyqt6_plugins-6.1.0.2.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl"
6. Open the folder "pyqt6_plugins-6.1.0.2.2.dist-info"
7. Open with a text editor the file "METADATA"
8. Find the line: "Requires-Dist: pyqt6 (==6.1.0)" and change to "Requires-Dist: pyqt6". Save the file.
9. Now your 2 files are ready, and you just need to manually pip install the files:

> pip install PyQt6-6.4.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl

> pip install pyqt6_plugins-6.1.0.2.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl

10. Done! You have installed Pyqt6 in Python 3.11!

All the credits to the user https://github.com/liudonghua123 that solved this problem to pyqt5 in https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/108, this is just the same solution but applied to pyqt6.

Comment: I can confirm this way works also for Python 3.12 (with obvious changes).

Comment: What are the 'obvious' changes for Python 3.12? @rok

Comment: That's what i did: do all the steps in this answer using version 6.4.2.2.3 for both pyQt6 and plugin (because the last available version is actually this one). Then designer should work, but the version of pyQt6 installed is bugged (dialogs won't show).. but you can upgrade pyQt to the latest version, designer will still work..

Comment: Thanks! In the meanwhile I actually installed the 40 GB of QT Creato to use Qt Designer... But I later found that here https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download there is a minimal installation for Qt Designer. Maybe I'll try it the next time and can anyway be useful to someone who just wants to use the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe PyQt6 is compatible with Python 3.10 or 3.11. you have to have Python 3.9. This is what I found but maybe someone else has found a different solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).