# Python 3.12, PyQt6, pyinstaller --noconsole, Trojan:Win32./ScarletFlash.A Error

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyqt6

I am currently trying PyQt6 for the first time.  Apparently, its last update was with Python 1.7, but I found instruction on how to install the tools and currently working to create an executable window with the PyQy6 Designer.

Everything works fine, until I try to run the pyinstaller with the --noconsole option to it, at which point my Antivirus software suddenly stops all operations and declares it found a Trojan:Win32./ScarletFlash.A.

Information on the virus says "is a heuristic detection designed to generically detect a Trojan Horse."  This seems to insinuate that it is finding only trojan like behavior, rather than the a virus itself, but I can't be entirely sure.

Basically, my steps are as follows:

1. Created the Python GUI interface using the pygt6-tools designer.
2. Created the test.py program using the "pyuic6 -x test.ui -o text.py" terminal command.
3. Created the text.exe program using the "pyinstaller --onefile test.py" terminal command.

This all works excellent at this point, the window comes up.  The problem was that it also opens a big console window, and I wanted to see if I could avoid that.  So I updated the last command line to "pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole test.py" at which point it stops cold and my virus detection software pops up saying it found the trojan virus.

Also, fyi:  The instructions I used to update the pyqt6 so it would install in the lastest python are found here at the following link...

[Cannot install PyQt6 tools in Python 3.11 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060996/cannot-install-pyqt6-tools-in-python-3-11-on-windows)

I cannot seem to find any other posts which find similar activity...  is this a false positive?  Have others come across this also?  Or should I be worried that my system is compromised?  If not, how should I handle this so that it will work properly, not only on my system but on any other system as well?